# Routing issue while using high_voltage for static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to use high_voltage to serve up static pages.  It seems to be working in that if I put .../pages/PAGE_NAME in the browser window it will bring up the correct page.  The problem that I am having is that the default root doesn't appear to be working properly. When I go to http://localhost:3000 I get the home.html.erb page that I put in the view/pages directory inside of my application.html.haml layout.  Basically, a page inside of a layout which is not what I expected.

I am following the instructions in that I have the following entries in my routes.rb file:

```
resources :pages
root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'home'
```

I also have a PagesController with the following code:

```
class PagesController < HighVoltage::PagesController
  layout nil
end
```

It appears that my root route does not actually hit the PagesController (with layout nil) that I have in my code. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this ?

```
root :module=> :high_voltage, :controller => :pages, :action => :show, :id => 'home'
```

see [root](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/root) and [match](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/match) (used internally by root) for more info.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks a bunch.  I need to digest why that works and why the first version didn't work.